# My "a" key is busted. I want to map to another key

Tags: keyboard, remapping

Other posts I've seen mostly seem to refer to special/modifier keys.

Is there a way to remap the <kbd>a</kbd> key to something else?

Cinnamon 17, 64-bit. I have a Japanese win keyboard.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use a virtual keyboard, for example **onboard**. Install it without the '**a**' key by copy and paste from here to a terminal window: `sudo apt-get install onboard`

Comment: so then use my mouse pointer to get my A?? from the VirtKB?  if so..  it might be  bit better thn trying to keep A  in my clipbord.  type ctrl-v ..  tht's getting old...  lol  --  hopefully somebody cn give me the steps for this..  but my reding mkes me think it my be  little more indepth thn I hve time for..  if nothing comes up by like Tues,  I'll grb  USB KB..  I'm  just trying to do it vi code cuz I m on  lptop nd don't wnt more prts to crry...

Answer (score 1):

### As a workaround, you can use a virtual keyboard, for example onboard

You can install `onboard` and when you run it, you will have a keyboard on the screen. You can click on it with the mouse (similar to what you do with a smartphone, when you type by touching the screen).

`onboard` looks like this in my Lubuntu 16.04 LTS in a desktop computer. It might look differently with another version of Ubuntu or in another computer, but would work the in same way.

[image]

Install `onboard` without the 'a' key by copy and paste from the next line to a terminal window,

```
sudo apt-get install onboard
```

You can also mark (press the left button while moving the cursor) and paste (press the middle button or wheel to paste) from here to the terminal window.

You can also install it via the Software Center, if you prefer a tool with a graphical user interface.

Comment: I hve onbord working.a

Comment: I have onboard working.  thanks  yea using it's transparency function is much better than trying to keep the a in my  clipboard all of the time. I suppose this means you re not aware of  a way to  remap the key.

Comment: That's right. I don't know how to do that. But if you are lucky, someone who knows will see your question and help you to remap '**a**' to some other key :-)